# Add componentDidMount in export default function and get the error of "Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: reactjs, api, components, material-ui

I was just take the drawer component from material-ui components. but I wan to change some code inside to call out my api. So I use the method of componentDidMount, but I get the error of `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"` in the componentDidMount. I also try to put it inside `export default function` but also get fail. I am not sure is it anyway I make a mistake? or is it any way I can get the fetch my API?

consider code below:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const loginEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
  this.setState({loginEmail})
  console.log(loginEmail)
  fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/view${loginEmail}`,)
    .then((resp) => {
      resp.json()
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data.user_info.id);
          //  localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.user_info.id);
          this.setState({data: res.data});
        })
    })
}
}

export default function PermanentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
   ...// the drawer code take from material-ui.com
  );
}
```

Comment: `componentDidMount(){}` is not valid JavaScript syntax. This is only valid inside object literals or classes.

Answer (score 1):

Other than a possible bad copy/paste job, you have a dangling comma in your `fetch` and an extra closing `}`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const loginEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
  this.setState({loginEmail})
  console.log(loginEmail)
  fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/view${loginEmail}`,) // <- dangling comma
    .then((resp) => {
      resp.json()
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data.user_info.id);
          //  localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.user_info.id);
          this.setState({data: res.data});
        })
    })
}
```

Remove the comma and unnest (i.e. flatten) your promise chain, and consistently use semicolons to end your expressions.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const loginEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
  this.setState({loginEmail});
  console.log(loginEmail);
  fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/view${loginEmail}`)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.user_info.id);
      //  localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.user_info.id);
      this.setState({data: res.data});
    });
}
```

Also, I think you've confused functional components and class-based components.`componentDidMount` is a class-based react component lifecycle function **only**; it doesn't work the same way in a functional component. As written, it isn't valid syntax; it would need to be inside an object or class (i.e. like a class-based component). The correct syntax to declare standalone functions is to use the keyword `function`.

```
function componentDidMount() {
  const loginEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
  this.setState({loginEmail});
  console.log(loginEmail);
  fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/view${loginEmail}`)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.user_info.id);
      //  localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.user_info.id);
      this.setState({data: res.data});
    });
}
```

Comment: FWIW, trailing parameter list commas are port of the spec now (or at least they will be (proposal page is currently not accessible)). Chrome supports it already.

Comment: Thanks, yes, but we've no idea what OP's IDE is, how it's configured(linter), or what browser they see the error in, so just covering all the bases.